# Java Null Pointer Exception when creating new instance of class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm in my first year of computer science and am having a hell of a time with a project. I was given the code that creates a list of room numbers via an array, and I am to create a method that allows the user to pick a room, enter in their information, and reserve the room.

My issue seems to lie in creating the method that actually reserves the room... which is as follows...

```
 public void bookRoom (Room[] room, int numberOfRooms)
{

    //Get settings for room (smoking, occupied, guest name/number)

    displayRoomsInfo(room, numberOfRooms);

        Room room1 = new Room(false, false, null, null, numberOfRooms);



    //user input,store each value to temp variables

    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose a room");

    int guestRoomNum=scan.nextInt();
    room1.setRoomNumber(guestRoomNum);

    //set room[i] occupied = true;

    room1.setOccupied(true);

    //set room[i] guestname to name

    System.out.println("Enter Guest Name");
    String dickshit = scan.next();
    String[] nameList = {dickshit};
    room1.setGuestName(nameList);



    //set room[i] guestnumber to phone

    System.out.println("Enter Guest Phone Number");
    String phoneInput = scan.next();
    room1.setGuestPhone(phoneInput);
    }
```

I keep getting a null pointer exception on

```
Room room1 = new Room(false, false, null, null, numberOfRooms);
```

Which is the line where I actually create an instance of the custom class that I was provided. I don't have a freaking clue as to why or how I can go about preventing this, since those appear the default constructor values.

The Room class code is as follows:

```
public class Room {

private boolean smoking;
private boolean occupied;
private String[] guestName=new String[4];
private String guestPhone;
private int roomNumber;

public Room (boolean smoking,boolean occupied,String[] guestName, String guestPhone,int roomNumber)
{
    this.smoking=smoking;
    this.occupied=occupied;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        this.guestName[i]=guestName[i];
    this.guestPhone=guestPhone;
    this.roomNumber=roomNumber;

}
public void setGuestName(String[] guestName)
{
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        this.guestName[i]=guestName[i];
}


public String[] getGuestName()
{
    String[] tempGuestName=new String[4];
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        tempGuestName[i]=this.guestName[i];
    return tempGuestName;
}

public void setOccupied(boolean isFull)
{
    this.occupied=isFull;
}

public boolean getOccupied()
{
    return occupied;
}


public void setSmoking(boolean canSmoke)
{
    this.smoking=canSmoke;
}

public boolean getSmoking()
{
    return smoking;
}


public void setGuestPhone(String phoneNumber)
{
    this.guestPhone=phoneNumber;
}

public String getGuestPhone()
{
    return guestPhone;
}


public void setRoomNumber(int roomNum)
{
    this.roomNumber=roomNum;
}

public int getRoomNumber()
{
    return roomNumber;
}
```

}

Comment: `this.guestName[i]=guestName[i];` `guestName` is passed `null` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get user input, and then make room for it?
After user has entered the data (and you saved it to variables)

```
Room room1 = new Room(false, true, nameList, phoneInput, roomNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your `Room()` constructor, you're doing this.

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    this.guestName[i]=guestName[i];
```

But you're passing `null` for the `guestName` as the parameter, which throws a NPE as your `guestName` array is `null`.

If you want to pass a `null`, remove the `for` loop from the constructor. If not, pass a blank `String[]` to the constructor.

```
Room room1 = new Room(false, false, new String[4], null, numberOfRooms);
```

Note that even when you do the above, each element in the `String[]` is still a `null` reference only and you need to explicitly initialize them in your program later.

Answer (score 0):

guestName is null in

```
 Room room1 = new Room(false, false, null, null, numberOfRooms);
```

but your constructor requires it not to be null

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    this.guestName[i]=guestName[i];
```

You should either add a test in your constructor :

```
if(guestName != null)
```

or pass a valid array when you call the constructor

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    this.guestName[i]=guestName[i];
```

The Argument guestName is null. Since you do not provide any value to it:

```
    Room room1 = new Room(false, false, null, null, numberOfRooms);
```

See the 3rd arugment.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying access **guest name** in constructor Which is null. Take care that , You Should not do any operation on on values those are passed/assigned/turned Null.